# Facebook Login Crash with iOS app (Thread 1 signal SIGABRT)

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, xcode9

how are you? I'm having a problem with the Facebook Login SDK.
The Facebook Login Button is shown in the app but when I try to click it in the XCODE Simulator, the app crashes and I have the following alert:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT
```

And I have other question, I would like to know if the Facebook Login runs on the XCODE Simulator, that is if I can login really into the app.

If you could help me I will appreciate it.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have mulitple "CFBundleURLTypes" keys in your Info.plist file. If so merge them into a single array with multiple dict elements.